# Assigning an element of a list to another (Python)

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find help assigning an element of a list to another.
To be specific, I am doing the "Sum of Intervals" challenge on Codewars.

> Write a function called sumIntervals/sum_intervals() that accepts an array of intervals, and returns the sum of all the interval lengths. Overlapping intervals should only be counted once.
>
> **Intervals**
>
> Intervals are represented by a pair of integers in the form of an
> array. The first value of the interval will always be less than the
> second value. Interval example: [1, 5] is an interval from 1 to 5. The
> length of this interval is 4.
>
> **Overlapping Intervals**
>
> List containing overlapping intervals:
>
> ```
> [
>   [1,4],
>   [7, 10],
>   [3, 5]
> ]
> ```
>
> The sum of the lengths of these intervals is 7. Since `[1, 4]` and `[3, 5]` overlap, we can treat the interval as `[1, 5]`, which has a length of
> 4.

I am confused as to why trying to assign an element of a list to another fails. Here is my code:

```
def sum_of_intervals(intervals):
    sum = 0
    for thing in intervals:
        thing = list(thing)
        for thing2 in intervals:
            thing2 = list(thing2)
            if thing[1] > thing2[0] and thing[1] < thing2[1]:
                if thing == thing2 and intervals.index(thing) != intervals.index(thing2):
                    intervals.remove(tuple(thing2))
                else:
                    thing[1] = thing2[1] #line that does not seem to be working
                    intervals.remove(tuple(thing2))
    for thing3 in intervals:
        sum += thing[1] - thing[0]
    return sum
```

Does anyone know why `thing[1] = thing2[2`] does not work? If I return `intervals` instead of `sum`, for example for `([(1,5),(3,7)])` it just returns `(1, 5)` or sum of 4.

If this question has been asked before (which it does not look like it has) please tell me and guide me there. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what `if thing[1] > thing2[0] and thing[1] < thing2[1]:` is supposed to do?

Comment: For the benefit of those of us who don't follow codewars, please explain what this is supposed to do.

Comment: @Barmar https://www.codewars.com/kata/52b7ed099cdc285c300001cd

Comment: It would be helpful if you used more meaningful variable names than `thing`, `thing1`, `thing2`. This isn't a Dr Seuss group.

Comment: Why are yuo converting things to tuples when you call `remove()`?

Comment: I recommend you either add `print()` calls or step through with a debugger to see what's happening.

Comment: @Hhadley I think it's supposed to be detecting overlapping intervals.

Comment: @Barmar For example, if intervals is [(1,5),(3,7)], and thing2 is a list, you cannot remove thing2 from intervals as the list [3,7] is not in intervals.

Comment: @brutalthebigone I thought the input was a list of lists, not a list of tuples. If it's not, you could simplify by converting it: `intervals = list(map(list, intervals))`

Comment: there multiple issues in this code, both algorithmic and syntactic: first it is a bad idea to write this (never happens): `if thing == thing2 and intervals.index(thing) != intervals.index(thing2):`. If thing == thing2, the method `.index()` will return the first instance of this identical element in both cases. If you want to remove duplicates, it's better to do so in the very beginning by writing `intervals = list(set(intervals))`

Comment: Then, if you write something like this `thing = list(thing)`, you create an absolutely new object of the type `list` that has little to do with the previous object. When one then starts to assign `thing[1] = thing2[1]`, he or she should not even expect to affect what used to be in `intervals`. The 2nd element of the completely new `thing` just starts to point to the 2nd element of the completely new `thing2`.

Comment: `intervals.remove(tuple(thing2))` will never remove anything, because there were no tuples in `intervals` in the beginning

Comment: `sum += thing[1] - thing[0]`??? Why inside the loop for `thing3` you handle the previous loop variable `thing`?

Comment: @Alex 
#1: Thanks I didn't realize that. 
#2: Maybe this is an answer, thanks 
#3: There were tuples, and it did get removed 
#4: I will use a thing3[1] - thing3[0] now, thanks for being helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the intervals contain only integers is a gross simplification of the task. It can be solved in one line:

```py
sum_of_intervals = lambda x: len(set.union(*[set(list(range(*i))) for i in x]))
```

Comment: Thank you for a solution, but I would like to know why assigning the value of an element of a list to another does not work.